# Where should I be posting this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-recommendation

I recently posted [Deconstructing Pokémon glitches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876642/deconstructing-pokemon-glitches) to Stack Overflow. I'm interested in learning the answer, and will probably start a very large bounty on the question soon.  However, I want to ensure that I'm not just throwing reputation away in the case the question is closed as off-topic.

Is Stack Overflow a reasonable place to post this question, or is there another site where I should ask the question?

Comment: SO seems reasonable for this question, IMO.

Comment: Huh, I would have said that [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) was a better place for it...

Comment: This is somewhat orthogonal to your question, but do note that a question with an active bounty cannot be closed. So you won't be throwing reputation away now that you've started the bounty. (Also, seems like a fair question to me. It's definitely programming-related, and is asking to solve a specific problem.)